# how to handle click events for html tags inside the info/window using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

i refer many of the codes now available here and around the internet. i m trying to find the answer but havent found any. i m providing my whole code below. i dont know now why it is not working. the page simply gets reloaded when i click a form submit button inside the infowindow . here is the code

```
<script>
var map;
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
function initialize()
{
    var mapProp = {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:5,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"),mapProp);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}
var contentstring = '<div id="infowindow_name">' + '<form id="mylocation_form" >'
    + '<input type="text" name="mylocation" id="mylocation" style="height:50px; width:300px; outline:none;"/>'
    + '<br />' + '<input type="submit" id="infowindow_submit" name="submit" value ="submit"/>'
    + '</form>'
    + '</div>';
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentstring

    });
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
        document.id("mylocation_form").addEvent("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("hi!");
        });
    });
    //deleting a marker on right click............................................
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

now in the above code, on the line `google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {........`,
the function is not working at all. the page is getting reloaded with nothing happening. i dont know how can i stop the form from submitting. aactually i need ajax to handle the submit part. i dont know why this domready function is not working. :(
please help and if u can provide a fiddle also it would be greatly appreciated.
i m totally a learner and m trying a lot to learn things. i really need help on this one
i used the following link code to create the domready function,
[Adding event to element inside Google Maps API InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378007/adding-event-to-element-inside-google-maps-api-infowindow)
and i had aslo tried the `e.stop()` function. it is not working

Comment: Have you defined the methods `id()` and `addEvent()` somewhere(it's not native DOM/JS)?

Comment: it worked. :):):):):):):):):):):):):):)..... i replaced the document.id("my_location_form").addEvent(...... with $("#mylocation_form").submit(function(e) {.....and it worked. :):):):)       thanks a lot to point out the mistake.