# How could I call a Angular2 function from a Google Map infowindow?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, angular, google-maps-markers

Google map is integrated the javascript way and I want to call a angular2 function inside an infowindow like the following code. Take a look at `infoContent` for the button.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  let locLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude);
  let infoContent = '<button (click)="myFunction(' + locations[i].id + ')">Details ...</button>';

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: locLatLng,
    map: this.map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
      infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
    };
  })(marker, i));

}
```

Unfortunately the angular click event `(click)="myFunction()"` can't do it. There must be an other way. I would be very pleased if someone can point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with your `addListener()`? If `this.map` is not working as expected see my answer below. Is there something else? Some error message, ...?

Comment: Opening the infowindow works fine. If I change the way from `(click)` to `onclick` I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`, but myFunction() is inside an angular component.

Comment: I guess you should use event delegation. You can also take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378007/adding-event-to-element-inside-google-maps-api-infowindow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update (from comment)**

You can do it with `ElementRef` and `Renderer` but that is not the problem. The problem is to get a reference (direct DOM element reference or `ElementRef`) of the button. You can inject `private elRef:ElementRef` and use `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('infowindow button')` or similar but if you access `elRef.nativeElement` you're out of the realm of platform neutrality again because `nativeElement` should not be accessed directly, but with the limitation of the `Renderer` of only being able to call methods but never to get a result in return, there is only so much you can do.

I would use a method like shown in [Trigger event with infoWindow or InfoBox on click Google Map API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102598/trigger-event-with-infowindow-or-infobox-on-click-google-map-api-v3) and then check the `event.target` if an element you are interested in was clicked.

**original**

If you want to access `this.map` in the event handler you should use arrow functions instead

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ((marker, i) => { // <<<===
    return () => { // <<<===
      infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
      infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
    };
  })(marker, i)
```

otherwise `this.` won't point to the current class instance

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this don't solve my problem. I tried the js way with `onclick` instead of `(click)` but I only receive a `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`.

Comment: I missed `  let infoContent = '<button (click)="myFunction(' + locations[i].id + ')">Details ...</button>';`. Angular2 doesn't process bindings added dynamically therefore this is not supposed to work. Only bindings added to component templates statically are processed by Angular2. You need to use `addEventListener()` for dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction. The angular2 way of addEventListener() seems to go throught `ElementRef` and `Renderer`. I try it out.

Comment: Yes, using `Renderer` and `ElementRef` is the platform-neutral way but if you use GoogleMaps you are outside this realm already anyway therefore it doesn't buy you much here. See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102598/trigger-event-with-infowindow-or-infobox-on-click-google-map-api-v3 for an example. Because `setContent()` takes a string, there is no way to add event handlers to individual elements. I assume you can get the actual element from the `MouseEvent` you receive from `click` events on the infowindow itself.

Comment: Yes, I know the answer above, but there must be a way to bind from outside the google map script. First I try it with ElementRef and Renderer. Let's see if this works.

Comment: You can do it with `ElementRef` and `Renderer` but that is not the problem. The problem is to get a reference (direct DOM element reference or `ElementRef`) of the button. You can inject `private elRef:ElementRef` and use `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('infowindow button')` or similar but if you access `elRef.nativeElement` you're out of the realm of platform neutrality again because `nativeElement` should not be accessed directly but with the limitation of the `Renderer` of only being able to call methods but never to get a result in return there is only so much you can do.

Comment: Muah. That seems to be difficult. Anyway. Thank you for your time. I have to go in lab :)

Comment: Maybe you want to rewrite your answer with the statement of your last comment. So I can mark it as right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can do the trick instancing a reference to ngZone in root Window and call it from inside the infoWindow.

First you need to get access to NgZone in constructor:

```
 constructor(public _ngZone: NgZone) {    }
```

And then you can set a pointer back to your zone in window, on **ngOnInit**, constructor or somewhere, depending of your code:

```
    window["angularComponentRef"] = { component: this, zone: this._ngZone };
```

Finally you can callback from infoWindow to your Angular function with zone.run like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        let locLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude);
        let infoContent: string = '<button onclick="window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(() => {window.angularComponentRef.component.myFunction(\'' + locations[i].id + '\');})">Details ...</button>';

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locLatLng,
            map: this.map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
                infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, i));

    }
```

And you can clean the function when needed to avoid polute the window namespace, on **ngOnDestroy** for example:

```
 window["angularComponentRef"] = null;
```

Comment: Dude! You rock!

Comment: holy crap, thanks a ton mate! saved my day, phew! been struggling with this for hours. cheers 

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. First, I set id to button in info window. After that, I caught 'domready' event for info window which means: all the HTML has been received and parsed by the browser into the DOM tree which can now be manipulated. And then with getElementById accessed to button and add event 'click'. Here you can call your function defined in ts file.

```
const infoWindowContent = '<h6>' + community.typeOfCommunity + '</h6>' +
          '<p>' + community.address.name + ' ' + community.streetNumber + ', ' + community.city + '</p>' +
          '<p>Manager: ' + community.manager.fullName + '</p>' +
          '<button  id="infoWindowButton">More info</button>';
        const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContent
        });

        marker.addListener('click', () => {
          infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
        });

        infoWindow.addListener('domready', () => {
          document.getElementById("infoWindowButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.myFunction();
          });
        });
```

Comment: Using Angular 13 I copied the `infoWIndow.addListener...` block verbatim and it worked. Much easier than other solutions I found.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this complete solution for this question.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        let locLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude);
        let infoContent = '<div style="padding: 0.5em;">' +
            '<h5 id="lt" style="font-size: 12px">'+locations[i].id +'</h5>'+
            '<button id="btn" style="font-size: 8px;" >Click</button>'+
            '</div>'

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locLatLng,
            map: this.map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
                infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, i));
    }

    infowindow.addListener('domready', () => {
        var val = document.getElementById('lt').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.myFunction(val);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Works only for single click event in infowindow, unable to use for multiple info window.

Answer (score -1):

I'm search a lot and found the answer:

You must use: $compile(htmlString)(scope)

In your example try this:

```
var infoContent = '<button ng-click="myFunction(' + locations[i].id + ')">Details</button>';

var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('anyElementId')).scope();
var compiled = $compile(htmlElement)(scope);
```

And then use:

```
infowindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
```

Wala!